# Any good C# code generator for using oracle stored procedures?

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, code-generation

I'm looking for a C# code generator which generate C# automatically to access stored procedures on Oracle Database.

For instance, if I have some packages on schema DEV like:

- PACKAGE1 with FUNC1, FUN2
- PACKAGE2 with FUNC3, FUN4

The generator creates code to run from C# the following code:

```
int a = PACKAGE1.FUNC1(12, 34, "hello");
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MyGeneration](http://www.mygenerationsoftware.com) is open source, is template driven, and the templates can be written in C#. So would meet your needs, or there might even by a template out their already.

Comment: link not working...

Answer (score 2):

[CodeFluent Entities](http://www.softfluent.com/products/codefluent-entities) is model-first tool that can be used to generate SQL Scripts for Oracle:

- Schema
- Tables
- Constraints (primary and foreign keys)
- Views
- Procedures (and associated Oracle Packages)
- Instances (data)

Application classes (C#) may also be generated with relative ease.

Answer (score 1):

- [CodeSmith Generator](http://www.codesmithtools.com/product/generator) - commercial software
- [MyGeneration](http://www.mygenerationsoftware.com/portal/default.aspx) - free
- [Metadrone](http://www.metadrone.com/) - free

See also [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393917/free-sql-server-stored-procedure-generator) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885733/stored-procedure-generator-tool/11376402).

Answer (score 0):

I have something close to what you want... it currently generates stored procedure wrappers for Python.  It's an open source package and you can fill in the template with the C# code you desire.

> http://markharrison.net/orapig/
>
> http://code.google.com/p/orapig/

I'd be happy to assist in getting this going.  My email address is in [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/116/mark-harrison) if you want to discuss further.