# Stored Procedure generator tool

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, code-generation

I am looking for tool which will generate the basic stored procedure structure (CRUD operations) for the given table, Is there any tool for the same?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For MS SQL there is [SSMS Tools Pack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/), works great!

Comment: This requires a license

Comment: @MattOakley Good info, this post was 2010 when it was free. Obviously now there are many new alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

Some stored procedure generators:

**General use**

- [CodeSmith Generator](http://www.codesmithtools.com/product/generator) - commercial software
- [MyGeneration](http://www.mygenerationsoftware.com/portal/default.aspx) - free
- [Metadrone](http://www.metadrone.com/) - free

**SQL Server-specific**

- [SSMS Tools Pack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/)
- [Stored Procedure Generator](http://spgen.codeplex.com/)

See also [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393917/free-sql-server-stored-procedure-generator) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785544/any-good-c-sharp-code-generator-for-using-oracle-stored-procedures).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to generate stored procedures to access your relational database system, you should look at [CodeFluent Entities](http://www.softfluent.com/products/codefluent-entities) which is free for personal and see if it can meet your needs.

This tools allows you to generate tables, stored procedures and views with relative ease
and it supports Microsoft SQL Server, Microsoft SQL Azure, Oracle, MySQL and PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this https://github.com/omids20m/FlexiSqlTools
this application generate CRUD store procedures and Search store procedure !

Answer (score 0):

Tools4SQL.net Stored Procedure Generator is really very good software and it generates more than 10 types of SP for MS SQL Server but it is commercial software.

Demo Version allows to generate SP for Tables which have columns less than 25.

[Tools4SQL.net Stored Procedure Generator](http://www.tools4sql.net/)